# WASAPI rendering the saved audio file

Tags: audio, rendering, naudio, wasapi

I am trying to play back the audio which was captured using waspi capture. The audio is saved in the form of wasapicapture.in file. Now the challenge is to play back the audio captured using wasapi renderer. I am able to play back, but the audio which I listen is always in stereo like, so its faster. I would like to reproduce that in original format. Could any help me please.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the file as Rawstream  , pass in the WaveFormat the audio so that you can get the original recordered clarity aswell.

Answer (score 0):

You could either save it into a .WAV file in the first place with `WaveFileWriter`, which will simplify playing it back. Or you can just read the file and pass it into a `RawSourceWaveStream` also passing in the `WaveFormat` the audio was originally recorded in.